# IAP or Authorize.net

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, authorize.net, applepay

We are going to build a mobile app for iOS and Android (might build a web app later) where users can upload videos and their friends and followers can watch them. The videos can be either free or also be tagged with a price. If I tag a video with $1 when uploading it, my friends and followers will have to first pay $1 to watch, and after paying that $1, they can watch it any time after that.

My question is that my client wants to use Authorize.net to do the payments. But from what I have read earlier, if we are buying things to be used inside the app, we should use IAP. But when I read the latest review guidelines today, I am not clear whether it mentions about a condition as above. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

This might be going under '3.1.3 “Reader” Apps:', but it also says:

> provided that you agree not to directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than IAP, and your general communications about other purchasing methods are not designed to discourage use of IAP.

So does that mean that we can really use a payment gateway like Authorize.net to do the payments for buying videos without using IAP and without the app getting rejected?

Comment: If the $1 is paid in the app then you need to use IAP.  If the $1 is paid on some other web site and there is no way of accessing that web site from the app then you could use some other payment system.  For example, if I buy an ebook *in* an app I must pay with IAP. If I have already bought a ebook directly on a website then it is OK if that book appears in the app if I log in

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. Do you have any links any official guidelines on this. Because earlier in the guidelines they said '11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected' . But in the new guidelines I don't see something like that. And as I have highlighted in the question that statement is bit vague. So was wondering whether they have removed that restriction.

Comment: @Paulw11 after reading your comment, now I am clear what it means by 'Reader Apps' in 3.1.3. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If you are charging customers for digital goods, you have to use IAP in iOS apps.

Last time when we submitted iOS app with third party payment solutions, Apple rejected the app.

Comment: Thanks @Basheer. When did you submit that version, was it recently or was it some time ago? Because earlier in the guidelines they said '11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected' . But in the new guidelines I don't see something like that.  And as I have highlighted in the question that statement is bit vague. So was wondering whether they have removed that restriction.

Comment: It was submitted around 3 months back. Apple replied saying app is not as per app store guidelines regarding IAP. read this section, https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

Comment: @Basheer Can you please check HotStar App ?

Comment: @NSPratik if you try to purchase hotstar premium membership through ios app, you have to pay through in-app purchase. Apple will not stop you from using third party payments in your site. It restricts only through your ios apps.

Comment: In iOS... Does HotStar do InApp?

Comment: Hotstar premium membership is the top in-app purchase. do check Hotstar app in iTunes / App store for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Apple clearly says that:

- If you sell physical good then you should implement payment method
  other than InApp Purchase.
- If you avail digital content (and that should be only within the
  App), then you must use InApp Purchase. Otherwise they will reject
  your app.

Better you convey client by sending link to Apple review guidelines.

> UPDATE

I found that [Hotstar](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/hotstar/id934459219?mt=8) iOS App uses third party payment gateway to make digital content available to premium user. We will have to look at it how Hotstar does it.

Find description [here](http://www.hotstar.com/terms-of-use).

Comment: Thanks @NSPratik . The current guidelines says 'If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase'. Does that apply to my feature as well? I am not sure. Because earlier guidelines mentioned that purchasing content must use IAP. But I don't see anything about purchasing contents in the latest guidelines. If you have any reference or links please share. Thanks

Comment: How a user's friend will able to watch particular video ? On iOS App or somewhere else ?

Comment: both uploading and viewing will be inside the iOS app. Later we might do that in a web app also. But all the uploading and viewing will be inside the mobile apps (both iOS and Android)

Comment: Then you must use IAP as content is being unlocked within the App.

Comment: that Hotstar app shows that 'offers in-app purchases'.  And under 'Top In-App Purchases' it shows Hotstar premium membership. Since they are already using In app purchase, may be the reviewers didn't worry much about the third party payment gateway you have mentioned.